# What is accuracy in "date" column type in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I found below statement regarding "date" column type:

> "date" stores only the date component
>   without the time component, ranging
>   from 1st January 0001 to 31st December
>   9999, with accuracy of 1 day

I am not able to understand what is meaning of accuracy here?

I found this statement on:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/News/3253/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the minimum difference from `date` to `date` is a single day, nothing less.

In other words, you can't store hours in a `date` column.

Or, that the data is accurate to within a day.

See [`date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) on MSDN:

- Range - 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31. January 1, 1 A.D. through December 31, 9999 A.D.
- Accuracy - One day

Answer (score 4):

day because it's "date"

Read [The ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp) by Tibor Karaszi

Answer (score 1):

The `date` type stores the value internally as an integer, meaning the number of days since 0001-01-01. The value `0001-01-03` for example would be stored internally as `2`.

The term "accuracy" is probably used here because it's used to express the resolution of other date/time types. The resolution for the `date` type is simply one day, just as you would expect. The accuracy (resolution) for the `datetime` type for example is 3.33 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

I agree the use of "accuracy" is poor wording.

Personally, I would employ the phrase, "its smallest time granule is one day."

Answer (score 0):

*Accuracy?*

It does what it says. It stores a date, not time...

From [date (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx)

**Element ranges**

> YYYY is four digits from 0001 to 9999
>   that represent a year.
>
> MM is two digits from 01 to 12 that
>   represent a month in the specified
>   year.
>
> DD is two digits from 01 to 31,
>   depending on the month, that represent
>   a day of the specified month.

where as

from [datetime (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

**Element ranges**

> YYYY is four digits from 1753 through
>   9999 that represent a year.
>
> MM is two digits, ranging from 01 to
>   12, that represent a month in the
>   specified year.
>
> DD is two digits, ranging from 01 to
>   31 depending on the month, that
>   represent a day of the specified
>   month.
>
> hh is two digits, ranging from 00 to
>   23, that represent the hour.
>
> mm is two digits, ranging from 00 to
>   59, that represent the minute.
>
> ss is two digits, ranging from 00 to
>   59, that represent the second.
>
> n* is zero to three digits, ranging
>   from 0 to 999, that represent the
>   fractional seconds.